# VS2015 Start BrowserLink Debug Browser with Command-Line options?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way in VS 2015 to start browser-link debug session with specific command-line options on Chrome like “--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com". My objective is to debug a domain & subdomain "combo" in an insecure (http://) environment but Google now limits “powerful feature” to secure environments (https://) and this is one of their preferred workarounds. See more [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins). I know that I can probably start a manual instance of Chrome to the debug server:port but it would be nicer if it were integrated. I've text-searched the entire project for "chrome.exe" as a start but nothing was there.

I’ve tried to set up a domain & subdomain with SSL and I’ve failed miserably, so this is a (hopefully) a workaround for now. :-)

**Edit2:** Additional info: I use a machine-name:port setup along with a subdomain embedded in an iframe. Ex: http://MyMachine:50080 and the iFrame is at 192.168.48.116.

Comment: Do you want to use the command for entire web application or just the content in iframe?

Comment: Ideally, at least for testing purposes, both the main frame AND the iframe. For now, just the iframe would do but that may change shortly. In my current config MyMachine:50080 can be left insecure while 192.168.48.116 is the iframe and needs to be secure. Localhost is considered secure on Chrome so theoretically I might be able to embed the iframe as localhost but that would involve changing some code which I haven't looked at yet. I have been able to test only the iframe as localhost but the hosting frame and the embedded iframe are programmatically connected so both would be far better...

Comment: @•Jack Zhai-MSFT - Sorry for the side post here regarding your edit for the removal of the visual-studio-debugging tag but I didn't know where/how else to mention this. This post is MOST definitely a VS debugging question in that I am looking to find a way/place where I can possibly add a command line option to the VS debugging action that starts the chrome browser. The "purpose" of the SO section is "Questions related to debugging methods and tricks in VS". Am I somehow misguided? Again my apologies for this comments here - if someone can tell me where to post this I will edit & repost. Thx.